# Compactness and connectedness in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

> Consider the set $$A=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb R^3: z=x^2+y^2+1\right\} \subset \Bbb R^3$$
>
> Prove of disprove: $A$ is connected and compact

The set $A$ is unbounded, since $(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n},2n+1)^t\in A$ with $$d(\textbf{0},(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n},2n+1))=\sqrt{2n+(2n+1)^2}>n$$ where $\textbf{0}$ denotes the origin in $\Bbb R^3$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. So $A$ is not compact.

Is this correct ? How about connectedness? Can I have a hint?

Comment: You're correct, it's not compact as not bounded.

Comment: For connectedness, try to visualize what this shape looks like. It's a bit like a truncated cone (like the tip was chopped off). It looks connected to me. Do you remember how to prove connectedness?

Comment: For connectedness, try writing your set as the image of a function from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$, and use the fact that the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected.

Comment: Connectedness comes from the ability to connect two arbitrary points on that surface with a continuous path. This is a surface of revolution, so you should be able to parametrize it in polar coordinate. That should make it super easy to then connect 2 points by a path.

Comment: @greelious: Is this function(?) works ? $$f:(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,x^2+y^2+1)$$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: @greelious: So $A$ is the continuous image of $\Bbb R^2$ under $f$ ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Yes, which means it is connected since $ \Bbb{R}^2$ is connected.

Comment: @StefanLafon . Connectedness is $implied$ by path-connectness (but not vice-versa) but  it's a good hint because path-connectedness  in this Q is not hard to show.

Comment: for path-connected, it would be easy as a first step to describe a path from $(0,0,1)$ to $(x,y,z)$ where $z=x^2+y^2+1$ (for any fixed $x,y$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3, f(x,y) = (x,y,x^2+y^2+1)$, establishes a *homeomorphism* between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A = f(\mathbb{R}^2)$. If $p : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2, p(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ denotes the (continuous!) projection, then $p \mid_A : A \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is the inverse homeomorphism. This shows that $A$ is connected but not compact.

Comment: Thanks!..........